# How do you set the text-overflow property of a highcharts-legend-item to ellipsis in styled mode?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I am trying to have legend items truncate to ellipsis and hovering over them show the whole name.
My legend

```
highchart.legend = {
                enabled: true,
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                navigation: { enabled: true },
                width: 100
            };
```

Because I am using highcharts in styled mode, this doesn't work.

```
itemStyle: {
    textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
    overflow: 'hidden'
},
```

I've tried this in CSS, but haven't had any luck.

```
.highcharts-legend-item text {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Any ideas? [JSFiddle showing the problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/jww910hy/)

Comment: Wouldn't you need some kind of width set for the text to overflow from?

Comment: Right I edited the post to show my legend, I set the width to 100, and it overflows. But it overflows by text-wrapping which I don't want.

Comment: I have edited one of [High Charts demos in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5q7mv5p/) and used your configuration for the legend and it does truncate the text. Can you edit it and save it to reproduce your problem maybe?

Comment: I think that the demo here isn't applicable as we are using the styled mode code base [Highcharts explanation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css) which doesn't perform the same way as the style by JS version. This shows the problem I'm having [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jww910hy/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `labelFormatter` function to your label which will truncate the legend name and add a title element (which provides the tool tip) to the legend text. It's a hacky solution with `setTimeout` to wait for the chart to render but it works:

```
labelFormatter: function() {
    var cut = 5,
        fullName = this.name;
    if (this.name.length > cut) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        let child = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",'title');
        child.innerHTML = fullName;
        document.querySelector(".highcharts-legend-item.highcharts-series-" + 
                               this.index).childNodes[0].appendChild(child);
      //if you have more then 1 chart at the page 
      //then you'll need to add the container id to the querySelector
      }.bind(this),200)
      return this.name.substr(0, cut) + "...";
    }
    return this.name;
  }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jww910hy/5/)

**EDIT:**
Based on Kamil Kulig's solution I've made a much shorter and less hacky solution using a wrapper function:

```
(function(H) {
  var old_buildText = H.SVGRenderer.prototype.buildText;
  H.SVGRenderer.prototype.buildText = function(wrapper) {
    wrapper.styles = wrapper.styles || {};
    wrapper.styles.textOverflow = 'ellipsis';
    old_buildText.call(this, wrapper);
    }
})(Highcharts);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qj0uL04/7/)

Comment: That is hacky, but much better than the hack I was doing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to force ellipsis in `Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.buildText` core function. Responsible line:

```
  ellipsis = true, //textStyles && textStyles.textOverflow === 'ellipsis', // force ellipsis
```

**Live working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/5qj0uL04/

Comment: I made a shorter version of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to retrict the width of legend item, the series name will auomatically set "text-overflow: ellipsis"

```js
legend: {
  itemWidth: 100
}
```